# Please share your thoughts on how to improve the below program. New coder wanting to learn how to better compuitational thinking

Tags: loops, primes, coding-efficiency

I wanted to create a program that lists all prime numbers to a given upper bound and that will provide the amount of primes in the set. After many hours of trial and error I was able to solve it.

I am sure this is not efficient and I want to learn how to look at code and see where improvements can be made. Or just to simply improve my computational thinking.

For instance, would it be better to not put this in an ArrayList?

Thanks in advance.

````
//Program should be able to print all primes between 1 and a given number and should also provide the amount of primes for the given set. 

public class NewPrimes {
    
    //Method to loop a value and to determine if the number is a prime. 
    public static void primes (int upperBound) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        for (int i = 2; i <= upperBound; i++) {
            if (i == 2) {
                arr.add(2);
            }
            for (int x = 2;(x < i) && (i % x != 0); x++) {
                if (x == i - 1) {
                    arr.add(i);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(arr);
        System.out.println(arr.size());
        
    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewPrimes.primes(1000);
        NewPrimes.primes(100);
        NewPrimes.primes(10000);        
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Have a look at the Sieve of Eratosthenes, which is an efficient way to find primes in a range.

Comment: This seems like a perfect question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, just needs its title changing to explain what the code does (e.g. "_Generate primes below a given bound_") and it would be suitable.

Comment: Thank you all. I will also post the question over on code review as advised.